# how does ValidationMessage method work in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Cananyone explain for me how does `ValidationMessage()` in asp.net mvc work.

I have read in [msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com) that it displays a validation message if an error exists for the specified field in the ModelStateDictionary object but when I tried to use it displayed the message error even without it happen.

This is my controller code

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public HomeController(logger parameter)
    {
        TempData["Hi"] = "Hi";
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult update(FormCollection collection)
    {
        data d = new data();
        TryUpdateModel(d , collection.ToValueProvider());
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Date", "Error");
        }
        return View("index", d);
    }
}
```

Model

```
public class data
{
    public int  Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my view code
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "index";
    }

```
<h2>index</h2>
@TempData["Hi"]
@Html.ValidationSummary()
@using (Html.BeginForm(new{action= "update"}))
{ 
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken() @Html.TextBox("id", 70)
    @Html.TextBox("Date", "3/2/1991 12:00:00 ص")
    @Html.ValidationMessage("Date","Error date format")
    <input type="submit"> 
}
```

And this is the output when I run the code for the first time without submitting the form

[image]

so please could anyone explain me that!.

Comment: You'd be better off using a data annotation in your viewmodel.

Comment: You need to go to the MVC site and work through the basic tutorials. Your get method should initialize an instance of the model and return it to the view. The view needs to declare thr model -  `@model yourAssembly.data` and use strongly typed helpers to correctly bind to your model properties - `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m =>m.Date)`. Then the POST method should be `public ActionResult update(data model)` so all model binding and validation is done out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

`ValidationMessage()` produces the HTML mark-up to display an error message.

`ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)` produces the mark up and shows an error message only if there is one associated with the field on your model.  The other great thing about this is that it works with the unobtrusive validation jQuery library that's available as a NUGET package.